# How can I start a program from a login batch script if the Command Prompt is disabled?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, login-script

Our Terminal Servers has two Group Policies in place: one that includes disabling the command prompt, and another that runs a batch script to startup a program upon login.

But the startup program never gets launched. I've tried running it manually and am getting an error that `"The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator"`, so I am guessing the command prompt restriction is getting applied before the login script gets run, but I'm not sure what I can do about this. (The program starts up fine if I login with a user that doesn't have the command prompt restriction)

Is there a way to run a .bat login script to startup a program on login, while still keeping the command prompt disabled?

The login script is simply `start \\networkshare\folder\someprogram.exe`, and our terminal servers are Windows 2003 and 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a logon script for this, why not just use the lesser-known [Run these programs at login](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314488) GPO. You shouldn't need to have the command prompt available for this.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware you could set startup programs through GPO like that. Starting the program from `Run these programs at login` worked :)